# MySQL SQL Subquery?

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the following schema / data / output how would I format a SQL query to give the resulting output?

> CREATE TABLE report (
> id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
> name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
> source VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
> PRIMARY KEY(id)
> ) ENGINE = INNODB;
>
> CREATE TABLE field (
> id BIGINT AUTO`_`INCREMENT,
> name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
> report_id BIGINT,
> PRIMARY KEY(id)
> ) ENGINE = INNODB;
>
> ALTER TABLE filed ADD FOREIGN KEY (report_id) REFERENCES report(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
>
> reports:
> id, name, source
> 1 report1 source1
> 2 report2 source2
> 3 report3 source3
> 4 report4 source4
>
> field:
> id, name, report_id
> 1 firstname 3
> 2 lastname 3
> 3 age 3
> 4 state 4
> 5 age 4
> 6 rank 4
>
> Expected output for search term "age rank"
> report_id, report_name, num_fields_matched
> 3 report3 1
> 4 report4 2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw, how can you put two "Age" values in the table "Field" when the column "name" is UNIQUE?

Comment: That was my mistake.  I got ahead of myself.  Upon testing  your code I had to edit the schema to remove a couple of unique statements.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return all the reports with words you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM report r
INNER JOIN field f ON r.id = f.report_id
WHERE name IN ('age','rank')
```

You have to nest it. So the final query is:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT r.id, r.name
    FROM report r
    INNER JOIN field f ON r.id = f.report_id
    WHERE f.name
    IN ('age', 'rank')
)a
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```